# Please identify cause of dead spots on my Malabar spinach

Tags: diseases, leaves, spinach

I noticed there are small spots on the plant, but they keep getting bigger and eventually turned brown, like dead spots on the leaf. How do I get rid of these? I've already cut all the affected leaves but they keep coming back on the new leaves.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is caused by a fungal infestation, and the rainy weather, which keeps the leaves moist, worsened the problem.